# Mouse coordinate conversion Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a camera:

```
//Map is a my object that wrapper of TiledMap class
```

In the create method:

```
this.renderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(this.map.getMap();
this.camera=new OrthographicCamera();
this.camera.translate(map.getMapPixelWidth()/2, map.getMapPixelHeight()/2);
this.camera.update();
view=new StretchViewport(map.getMapPixelWidth(),map.getMapPixelHeight(), camera);
batch=new SpriteBatch();
```

In the update method:

```
this.renderer.setView(this.camera);
this.renderer.render();
this.camera.update();
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

ArrayList<RectangleMapObject> layer=this.getObjectsFromLayer("collision");//find collision layers
//Mouse coordinates
int x=Gdx.input.getX();
int y=Gdx.input.getY();
Vector3 coordinateScreen=new Vector3(x,y,0);
Vector3 coordinateWorld=camera.unproject(coordinateScreen);
Rectangle rectMouse=new Rectangle(coordinateWorld.x,coordinateWorld.y,20,20);
for(RectangleMapObject rect: layer)
if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(rectMouse, rect.getRectangle(), rectMouse)){
                    System.out.println("COLLISION MOUSE-MAPOBJECT ");}


public ArrayList<RectangleMapObject> getObjectsFromLayer(String layerName){

        ArrayList<RectangleMapObject> array=new ArrayList<RectangleMapObject>();

        MapObjects og=this.map.getMap().getLayers().get(layerName).getObjects();

        for(MapObject object : og)
            if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) 
                array.add(((RectangleMapObject) object));
        return array;
}
```

My problem is that the collision between mouse and mapobject never occurs Also if I click on the area where stands the MapObject.
I think it is a problem of conversion of the coordinates of the mouse.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: The x/y coordinates of a Rectangle are the bottom left corner. It's not the center. Maybe try `Rectangle rectMouse=new Rectangle(coordinateWorld.x-10,coordinateWorld.y-10,20,20);`

Comment: Thank you but have not been able to solve the problem. This is the coordinates when I click on MapObject:                                   Mouse x: 137.99998 Y: 649.55554
MapObject x: 32.0 Y: 672.0

Comment: I don't know where that difference comes from, but you maybe better check for the intersection via `rect.getRectangle().contains(new Vector2(coordinateWorld.x, coordinateWorld.y))`

Comment: does not work, what else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Try int y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() - 1;

Comment: This is a Y of mouse coordinate?

Comment: no it does not work anyway, you could help if I sent you the tiledmap?